# Working out which day a linux epoch time belongs in Java

Tags: java, datetime, epoch

I am trying to work out how I would figure out which day a given Linux Epoch TS belongs to.

To help explain more, I am giving the following example:

I have had a go at this using JODATIME, but couldn't get a working solution.

```
// some code here that I need.... <---??

// The time set here below is (Tue 2019-09-10 14:05:00 UTC)
final long timestamp = 1568124300000L


if (timestamp = xxxxx) {
    System.out.println("The day it belongs to is: " + dayEpoch);
}
```

Ideally I want the output to be printed is:

> The day it belongs to is: 2019-09-10

Would appreciate if you give an example of code to achieve this :)

Comment: [Unix epoch time to Java Date object](//stackoverflow.com/q/535004)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Today no one wants a `Date` object, or at least should not want one. The `Date` class is poorly designed and long outdated. A `LocalDate` will serve the questioner much better. `LocalDate` is from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `java.time` to meet your requirement(s):

**First option (preferred): `OffsetDateTime`**

```
final long timestamp = 1568124300000L;

// create an Instant from the timestamp
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp);
// create a datetime object from the Instant
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
// print it in your desired formatting
System.out.println("The day it belongs to is: "
                    + offsetDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")));
```

**Second option (valid, but less appropriate): `ZonedDateTime`**

```
final long timestamp = 1568124300000L;

// create an Instant from the timestamp
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp);
// create a datetime object from the Instant
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
// print it in your desired formatting
System.out.println("The day it belongs to is: "
                    + zonedDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")));
```

> Please note that you can have different `ZoneId`s. You have clearly written that it is UTC in your case, so I took that one for the example. There is `ZoneId.systemDefault();` to get a local timezone, the output for that is the same (**date**) on my system.
>   **For using this, you will have to be using *Java 8* or the [ThreeTen-Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)…**

Comment: Very good answer. The attention that the answer gives to time zone is crucial, thank you. Instead of `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")` just use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE`.

Comment: One could also write `"The day it belongs to is: " + localDateTime.toLocalDate()` and skip the DateTimeFormatter entirely.

Comment: **`LocalDateTime` is the wrong class** to use here. As explained in its Javadoc, that class cannot represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. Your use here strips away the vital information about time zone or offset-from-UTC with nothing gained to compensate for that loss.

Comment: @BasilBourque yes, you're right, I should have used a `ZonedDateTime` or an `OffsetDateTime`, but the answer seems to be sufficient for Saffik (OP). I will update this soon for future readers… Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: For UTC, `OffsetDateTime` would be more appropriate than `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: @BasilBourque for the sake of completeness and use of appropriate classes, I provided both options. Thanks again.